# How to setup schedulign and autoscaling for CPU and GPU node groups in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Can you please kindly help me to understand how to configure proper pods balancing and nodes autoscaling in my AWS EKS cluster.
So, i have AWS EKS cluster with two node groups:

- one SpotNodeGroup with SPOT t3.medium instances (Min size - 0, Max size 16, desired 1)
- one MainNodeGroup with OnDemand m6i.large instances (Min size - 0, Max size 16, desired 1)
- one GPUNodeGroup with SPOT GPU instances "g4dn.xlarge","g4dn.2xlarge","g4dn.4xlarge","p3.2xlarge" (Min size - 0, Max size 16, desired 1)
- one GPUODNodeGroup with on-demand GPU instances g4dn.xlarge, min - 0, max - 8, desired 1

I have installed AWS autoscaler, and it's working basically - it is scaling up and down.
I have installed 12 services, 7 of them use GPU (they have nvidia.com/gpu: "1" in resources and limits section )and 5 is CPU-only.

I would like to achieve the following schema:

1 service replica should run on ondemand instance, and 1 replica on SPOT instance, and scale up more on SPOT to 4 replicas. And i need to minimize nodes count, for example, if it's possible (all services have resources specified) to run CPUService1, CPUService2 and GPUService1 on the one GPU node - it's much better.

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried adding Taints, [Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/), and Pod and Node Affinities? 
Most of your use case should be solved by that.

You can also try using [Pod Topology Spread](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, i need to achieve the following simple schema: i have 4 nodes - all with labels "CPU" and one node with label "ONDEMAND" and other 3 nodes with label "SPOT", and my application - 4 pods, and i would like place 1 pod on node with label "CPU" and label "ONDEMAND", and others 3 to distribute between nodes with labels "CPU" and "SPOT".

Answer (score 0):

I have found working schema for me.
I have created 2 deployments of one service:

- app-ondemand
- app-spot

First one, app-ondemand, has NodeSelector with ondemand node, and second is with spot selector. But both of them have same labels for balancing, so balancer distribute traffic between all pods.